# Round number using NSNumberFormatter without using strings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rounding, nsnumberformatter

This seems really simple but I can't see that NSNumberFormatter has a function for this which is strange. I have a number, lets say 4.1. I want to round that to 5. I figured if I used NSNumberFormatter and set the roundingMode to NSNumberFormatterRoundUp I would get the desired result. But the only way I seem to be able get my number to round now is either stringFromNumber or numberFromString. Seems odd that I just can't keep it a number.

I know I could just convert the string to a number but it seems like such a waste. Wanted to know if there was a different way (round() wouldn't round up if the number was 4.1) or if there is a method I missed looking through the class ref.

Cheers

Comment: o_o''.... any reason why you would want to round 4.1 to 5? Just curious. You dont want the number to go over 4.5 then round 5?

Comment: Formatters are always for converting data to and from strings. There is probably a library function to do what you want, I'll take a quick look, but right now your title is asking for something unreasonable.

Comment: @Pavan - It's for UI purposes, if its 4.1 I require 5 lines, if its 3.9 I require 4 lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the standard c function `ceil`

```
CGFloat number = 4.1;
CGFloat roundedUp = ceil( number ); // Will be 5.0
```

Comment: Make sure `number` is a float and not an NSNumber, though. Otherwise use `[number floatValue]`.

Comment: Cheers, worked like a charm. Got confused for a sec though cause all my numbers were int's, changed one to a double so it would calculate right

Answer (score 2):

You can use native C functions in Objective C. What you are after is `ceil()`. If you already have an `NSNumber` you can use the object methods such as `floatValue` to get a native C `float`.

```
float num = [ns_number floatValue];
num = ceil(num);
```